# Outputting XML feed breaks when executing PHP syntax

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to MVC a simple XML feed of images based on this structure.

This will always go from 1 - 20.

```
<image1>http://test.url/test.jpg</image1>
<caption1>This is a test caption <caption1 />
<credit1>This is a test credit</credit1>
```

and here's my script:

```
echo "<images>"; 
for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) { 
   $imageUrl = "image$i";
   $caption = "caption$i";
   $credit = "credit$i";
   echo "<image no='$i'>";
   echo "<imageurl>" . $gallery->$imageUrl . "</imageurl>";
   echo "<caption>" . $gallery->$caption . "</caption>";
   echo "<credit>" . $gallery->$credit . "</credit>";
   echo "</image>";
}
echo "</images>";
```

That gets returned as a variable `$xml` which I output like this:

```
$xmlProcessor = new GalleryXMLProcessor();
$xml = $xmlProcessor->processFeed("http://testurlexport.php");
header('Content-Type: text/xml;  charset=UTF-8');       
echo $xml;
```

However, I simply get the output returned as text and not XML. It appears to simply `echo`. I have an XML viewer on Chrome and that doesn't render the XML into its intended UI. Before I started adding images, this worked fine (see below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the echo is returning text/xml. Try changing the mime type of the returned xml to application/xml